# Extend table by adding missing values

Tags: r, matrix

I need to extend a `table` in **R language**.

```
result   3   4   5   6   7   8
     5   6  29 295 104   6   0
     6   1   9 112 238  66   5
     7   0   0   5  29  40   6
```

Should be extended to

```
result  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
     1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
     2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
     3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
     4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
     5  0   0   6  29 295 104   6   0   0    0
     6  0   0   1   9 112 238  66   5   0    0
     7  0   0   0   0   5  29  40   6   0    0
     8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
     9  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
```

So I need add zeros in missing values. Also, in alternative scenario an output as a `matrix` (10x10) with the same data would be satisfying.

**EDIT:**

`table(factor(x, levels = 1:10), factor(y, levels = 1:10))` worked perfectly.

Comment: If you factor before you create your table, you would have the output you desire.

Comment: `x <- sample(2:6, 10, TRUE);
y <- sample(3:5, 10, TRUE);
table(factor(x, levels = 1:10), factor(y, levels = 1:10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the guys in the comments mentioned. Factoring works perfectly.

`table(factor(x, levels = 1:10), factor(y, levels = 1:10))`